# ios in-house deployment, as a developer, how-to deploy the same application for multiple enterprises (with same app ID and multiple account)

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment, air, enterprise

I'm working in a software editor company, and we make application with adobe AIR.
Until now, we had always deployed applications for PC and Android, but now, I have to deploy an application to iOS.

The fact is we have developped one application, and we deploy it for multiple enterprises which make the same job.
they are franchised companies, same work, same application, but not same companies as a legal point of view.

Today, we asked our customer to pay an enterprise developper account to Apple (with them DUNS numbers), and add me as admin member. 
=> Is it the way if I want to deploy an iOS application made by me, paid by my customer ? I have to ask my customer do pay every year an enterprise account to Apple, I can't deploy with my account?

The real problem is then I want to use the same application ID to deploy to all.
So, when I want to add an App ID on their account, the webSite tells me the ID is already used, that's normal, it's me with my company account !

But, how can I deploy an application which has the same App ID to multiple companies with multiple enterprises developer account ?
Do I have to deploy with an provisionning profile ? Or can I deploy it only with a certificate made with their account, and my provisionning profile company ?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** use the **same App Id** (Bundle Id) for **several developer accounts**. If using several developer accounts is required condition then you should to use unique App id for every account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But, the problem is opposite, how can I deploy one application with multiple certificates ? Is it possible, ? Or have I to deploy with certificate and provisionng profile providing both from the same Apple account ?

Comment: You can deploy one application with multiple certificates only in case if these certificates belong to the same developer account.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an enterprise distribution profile to do this, but you should have added the enterprise account under your company.  Then build and sign with the enterprise profile and both companies can install and run the app on their employee devices.

Note, without MDM, the employees will have to trust your company's enterprise developer account before they can run the app, but that's how enterprise app distribution works.